# HTML - CSS Styling: Having separate colored elements on the same line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get the blue "65" to be on the same line as the header "Other". I've included an image as well as the current html.

Image:

[image]

HTML:

```
<h3 id="otherHead" class="groupHeader">Other <div style="color: #5191CD;">65</div></h3>
```

I have a script that injects the '65' into the header, which works, but I want to have the '65' be a different color and on the same line as 'Other' without having to use a table.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `display inline-block;`

```
<h3 id="otherHead" class="groupHeader">Other <div style="color: #5191CD; display: inline-block;">65</div></h3>
```

You shouldn't be styling against elements directly. Consider moving your element styles into a CSS style sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Add style display:inline-block

Here is the fiddle for the same

https://jsfiddle.net/ud7mjmcd/

```
<h3 id="otherHead" class="groupHeader">Other <div style="color: #5191CD;display:inline-block">65</div></h3>
```